# Cocoa events order

Tags: cocoa, events, notifications, mouseevent, cocoa-bindings

I have an application in which I'm monitoring 3 events/notifications:

```
mouseDown
NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification
NSWorkspaceDidDeactivateApplicationNotification
```

The case I'm trying to monitor is when clicking with mouse on my application.

I see that the ordering of event is not constant. Sometimes the order is:

> mouseDown -> NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification ->
>   NSWorkspaceDidDeactivateApplicationNotification

and sometimes:

> NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification -> mouseDown ->
>   NSWorkspaceDidDeactivateApplicationNotification

So the question is:
1) Are those events/notifications all handled by the main thread?
2) Is this a normal behavior and I can't actually expect an constant order?

Comment: Can't you just assume it's active if mouseDown is received?